# Twilio Studio - Main Flow - Subflow - Autopilot -Subflow variable handling and accessing

Tags: twilio

I'm new to Twilio Studio and I scanned through a lot of docs and SO articles, yet I'm not sure if I'm approaching this issue from the wright angle.

I want to build a programmable (SMS) chat with Twilio where a Property **Owner** or a **Tenant** can initiate a chat.

Here is the general flow:

- Incoming text message
- handover phone number and such to my backend REST API
- backend REST Api identifies if incoming number is registered in my DB and responds with a **backend JSON object** with details about either Owner or Tenant
- Split Widget to direct to either an Owner or a Tenant **Subflow**
- in (say) Owner Subflow initiate **Autopilot** to collect various data from the Owner
- surface back in origin Subflow to **act on that data** (i.e. POST to backend etc)

**Here's where I'm confused:**
I understand it's not possible to just take the original **backend JSON object** and pass it through the MainFlow -> SubFlow -> Autopilot -> SubFlow train (*which, I think, is a real pity IMHO* :))

So, is the only way to pass this data through the individual steps from above to flatten my beautiful JSON object :) at the handover point into **SubFlow via Subflow Parameters**.
Then again define the **Inbound Context Parameters** from the Subflow to the Autopilot?

And how would I access **Autopilot variables** when the Autopilot widget resurfaces back in the Subflow?

Any help is highly appreciated! Thank you.

[image: Main Flow]

[image: Sub Flow]

Answer (score 1):

Try sending your JSON object as a KEY:VALUE parameter in the run subflow widget. Then you can access any piece of data of your JSON and send it to autopilot

Comment: Yes, @jack, that's correct. I guess, it's more like a rant about Twilio not allowing to pass JSON objects in the first place ;)